# python enabled gdb for windows

Tags: python, gdb

I am using gdb 7.4 on a windows 7 machine
When I attempt to execute python script I get 
"Python scripting is not supported in this version of GDB"

I thought that it was supported in 7.4?
Where can I get a version of gdb that is python enabled for windows?

Comment: Have you tried googling the error message?

Comment: @mhawke I did and this question was first result.

Comment: @TomášZato: this question is now 4+ years old. I'm pretty sure that this question was not known to google at the time it was asked :)

Comment: @mhawke The lesson here is that it is not wrong to ask question about something because one day that question will be top google result on that problem.

Comment: @TomášZato: I see your point, but who said that it was wrong to ask the question? Anyway the OP should accept the answer, if the one given is correct. That would make the question and answer more valuable.

Answer (score 12):

You need a GDB which is built **with python enabled** (GDB.exe needs to link to python libraries, such as python27.dll for python2.7.x)
[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) supply python enabled GDB, [MinGW-W64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) sites also supply python enabled GDB, also [my unofficial build GDB](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=11301.0).

Comment: @user1414413: if this answer correctly identified and solved your problem please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

In mingw installer you need to install a special package called mingw32-gdb-python.
Which is the gdb compiled with python enabled